# Workflow Foundation 4.5 Exception Handling

Tags: c#, wcf, workflow-foundation-4

I have a very simple, long-runnig, message based, WCF Workflow and I'm facing a problem because whenever I have to throw a exception back to the who sent a message to the workflow, even if its by propous (i mean that the exception raised was mistakenly not treated...) the workflow instance goes to a "failure" state that cannot be continued...

what i want is to know how to turn this off... say like don't change the state of the workflow to "error"! something in the order of "throw and continue"...

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a WCF FaultContract on your Receive/SendReply pair.

See this article http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2010/03/24/workflow-4-and-soap-faults.aspx